# bootstrap/ui components, one vs many

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This may come across as sounding a little confused, but I'm wondering what's the opinion of people out there when it comes to making your website's UI rely on bunch of small open source packages/libs versus some singular comprehensive purchasable 'professional' collection of components?

And how come there appears to be none of the latter that rely on and play nicely with the ubiquitous bootstrap? (Bootstrap itself lacks many complex components that everybody wants: Datepickers for instance).

It seems like it is not a discouraged practice to have your website a fragmented mass of various js libraries (assuming they fit nice together). I guess the promotion of the open source graceful unobtrusive (etc) ideals has meant that 
there's more and more little handy homemade things out there... (I may be over simplifying)

Anyway, it's obviously initially cheaper to go with open source packages (than a paid product), but I guess the trade off is you get something slightly less reliable, and you probably have to work and/or wrap each one a little to get it to behave the way you want it.
Maybe in some circumstances that work might actually be less time consuming than any work required to make a comprehensive ui library look the way you want it.... for instance, I think if your site is gonna sit upon bootstrap, then you probably want the whole thing to look like bootstrap... but this brings me back to my first question - why can't I find anything like this?

Comment: This question is not well suited for Stack Overflow since it will result in opinion-based answers. Stack Overflow is geared towards helping you get concrete answers with debugging specific programming code that you have written, opinion-based answers are frowned upon by the SO community.

Comment: You could argue any decently justified opinion is as concrete as a slice of arbitrary code.

Comment: I don't make the SO policies. Just trying to help you out as a new user. Opinion-based questions are frequently closed by the SO community. According to this post "primarily opinion-based - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well.": http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions